# How do you detect if Terraform script is running in plan or apply mode?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using Terraform local-exec provisioner to run powershell script to create ILB ASE in Azure (ILB ASE not yet directly supported in Terraform Azure provider so we manually do it in Powershell).  We don't want to create ILB ASE while local-exec is running in plan mode since this operation takes 2 hours.   Is there a way for local-exec to detect if terraform script is running in plan or apply mode?

Comment: I do not really understand your question. It's in the plan mode when you run `terraform plan` and in apply mode when you run `terraform apply`. Is any issue here?

Comment: The `local-exec` provisioner won't run in plan mode so this isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provisioner do not run during the plan phase.

```
~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:31:16 PM
▶ cat .\main.tf
resource "null_resource" "localtest" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "New-Item -Name test"
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}

~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:31:19 PM
▶ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
- Downloading plugin for provider "null" (hashicorp/null) 2.1.2...

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.null: version = "~> 2.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:31:26 PM
▶ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.localtest will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "localtest" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.


~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:31:32 PM
▶ dir test
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\pearcec\projects\test\test' because it does not exist.

~\projects\test ⚡ ⨯                                                                                                                           ◷ 3:32:01 PM
▶ terraform apply -auto-approve
null_resource.localtest: Creating...
null_resource.localtest: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.localtest (local-exec): Executing: ["pwsh" "-Command" "New-Item -Name test"]


null_resource.localtest (local-exec):     Directory: C:\Users\pearcec\projects\test

null_resource.localtest (local-exec): Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
null_resource.localtest (local-exec): ----                 -------------         ------ ----
null_resource.localtest (local-exec): -a---           7/22/2020  3:32 PM              0 test

null_resource.localtest: Creation complete after 0s [id=5060708809844859353]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:32:22 PM
▶ dir test
-a---         7/22/2020   3:32 PM        0   test

~\projects\test ⚡                                                                                                                             ◷ 3:32:25 PM
▶
```